# Why does not work SQL query Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have the following SQL query:

```
return User::where("users.id", $id)
            ->select(array('rating.rate', User::raw('count(offers.id) AS ofrs, count(announcements.id) as appts')))
            ->join('announcements', 'users.id', '=', 'announcements.user_id')
            ->join('offers', 'users.id', '=', 'offers.user_id')
            ->join('rating', 'users.id', '=', 'rating.user_id')
            ->group_by('ofrs')
            ->get();
```

It gives me an error:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2508: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::group_by()

Why does not work group by?

Also as way I tried:

```
  return User::where("users.id", $id)
            ->selectRaw('rating.rate, count(offers.id) AS ofrs, count(announcements.id) as appts')
            ->groupBy('appts')
            ->groupBy('ofrs')
            ->join('announcements', 'users.id', '=', 'announcements.user_id')
            ->join('offers', 'users.id', '=', 'offers.user_id')
            ->join('rating', 'users.id', '=', 'rating.user_id')
            ->get();
```

Result:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1056 Can't group on 'appts'
```

I have written SQL query directly in SQL:

```
select rating.rate, COUNT(offers.id) AS ofrs, COUNT(announcements.id) as appts from `users` left join `announcements` on `users`.`id` = `announcements`.`user_id` left join `offers` on `users`.`id` = `offers`.`user_id` left join `rating` on `users`.`id` = `rating`.`user_id` where `users`.`id` = 1
```

It works, by model is not:

```
return User::where("users.id", $id)
            ->selectRaw('rating.rate, COUNT(offers.id) AS ofrs, COUNT(announcements.id) as appts')
            ->leftJoin('announcements', 'users.id', '=', 'announcements.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('offers', 'users.id', '=', 'offers.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('rating', 'users.id', '=', 'rating.user_id')
            ->get();
```

This work:

```
return User::where("users.id", $id)
            ->selectRaw('rating.rate, COUNT(offers.id) AS ofrs, COUNT(announcements.id) AS appts')
            ->leftJoin('announcements', 'users.id', '=', 'announcements.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('offers', 'users.id', '=', 'offers.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('rating', 'users.id', '=', 'rating.user_id')
            ->groupBy('rating.rate')
            ->get();
```

Comment: `groupBy('ofrs')` not `group_by`

Comment: I tried `groupBy('ofrs')`

Comment: Do you have the relationships set up in your User model for `announcements`, `offers` and `rating`?

Comment: Relatively Users?

Comment: But problem in SQL query, not in models

Comment: I can see see that :) However, I'm trying to offer you an alternative to using the query builder. Also, what are you hoping to achieve with `groupBy('appts')`?

Comment: I updated question with working sample, but I can not explain why it does work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read on how SQL works. You can't group by counted alias. What you are looking for is probably three queries or three relations.

You should create relation on User for announcements, second one for offers and third for ratings.

Than you would `User::find($id)->announcements->count()`, `User::find($id)->offers->count()` and `User::find($id)->ratings->count()`

Or you can use your Fluent way with something like:

`return User::find($id)
            ->leftJoin('announcements', 'users.id', '=', 'announcements.user_id')
            ->count();`

Answer (score 2):

The function name you're calling for group by is incorrect. Try:

```
->groupBy('ofrs')
```

See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) for more.

Comment: The edit to your question is a completely different problem. In that case, you appear to be trying to group on your counted aggregate. What exactly are you trying to achieve here? This is an entirely different kind of question to your original.

Comment: I need to join table User with others tables and to amount rows in related tabled for current user

Comment: So you're effectively trying to get the count of offers and announcements for each user?

Comment: I have written this Query directly in SQL: `select rating.rate, COUNT(offers.id) AS ofrs, COUNT(announcements.id) as appts from `users` left join `announcements` on `users`.`id` = `announcements`.`user_id` left join `offers` on `users`.`id` = `offers`.`user_id` left join `rating` on `users`.`id` = `rating`.`user_id` where `users`.`id` = 1`  It works, but in Laravel does not

Comment: Look question please

Comment: The difference is that in your SQL query, you're not grouping by anything. Why not try to group by the user?